# What houseplant is this and what conditions does it like?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, indoors

[image]

Hello, I've had this houseplant for a few months but it doesn't seem to be very happy. Can anyone please identify it so I can make sure it's in the right conditions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Dracenea massangeana, generally very tolerant , I have one descended from an original plant  from over 50 years ago.  I can only guess yours has too much or too little water.  When too dry for a long period , the tips of the leaves will turn brown , so more likely too wet. Sometimes called "corn plant". Addition: Mine is outside for the summer months and we have had several rains in the last week and mine is sitting in a flooded saucer now, this is not unusual . But I have never seen your condition caused by wet conditions ( of one week +). Have you used any additions to the soil and what soil are you using?

Comment: excellent answer; also, some coarse gravel etc in the bottom of it to improve drainage & aereation